# How to Modify Bootstrap Collapse with a unique id for open and closed state on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, local-storage, stringify

I have built a expanding tree-list using **bootstrap collapse.**. **(Without accordion,** which seems to be rare I learnt when trying to google it) The first problem I encountered was that the open/closed position of each item **on page reload**, wasn't recorded and therefore needs to be saved using local storage. Easy.

**However,** The subsequent problem is getting each tree-item to act individually and not remembering each other's position. Thus we need to generate a unique ID for open and closed state for **each individual** item so that they won't open and close together.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to SPViradiya for providing this easy solution combining both open, closed and **rotating arrow,** with little HTML and CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/SPViradiya/nm6tqxsL/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getUniqueID = localStorage.getItem('uniqueid');
if( typeof getUniqueID == "string" )
{
    var parsedUID = JSON.parse(getUniqueID);
  if( parsedUID != "" && typeof parsedUID == "object" )
  {
    for( item in parsedUID )
    {
        if(parsedUID[item])
        {
         $( "#"+item).collapse('show');
         console.log($( "div[href='#"+item+"']"));
         $( "div[href='#"+item+"']").addClass('rotateOn');
        }
        else
        {
         $( "#"+item).collapse('hide');
         $( "div[href='#"+item+"']").removeClass('rotateOn');
        }
    }
  }
}

$('.expand').click(function() {
    //store the id of the collapsible element
     $(this).toggleClass('rotateOn');
   setTimeout(function(){
    var uniqueid = {};

    $('.expand').each(function(){
       var getID = $(this).attr('href').replace(/#/g,'');
       uniqueid[getID] = $("#"+getID).hasClass('in');
    }); 
    localStorage.setItem('uniqueid', JSON.stringify(uniqueid)); 
   },500);



});

})
```

Comment: Can you please get us some HTML structure? I think you should need to store all branches parent id with needed status in json format and loop through them on load.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply - I've added the HTML. Alright, could you elaborate?

Comment: Can you show your expanding tree list as a working demo? You can create a code snippet in question to provide a demo. Or just the code of your tree list pasted in your question. [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The HTML structure of the tree is right there, so is the javascript.  I'll try to create a fiddle.

Comment: JSfiddle has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code on document ready

```
var getUniqueID = localStorage.getItem('uniqueid');
if( typeof getUniqueID == "string" )
{
    var parsedUID = JSON.parse(getUniqueID);
  if( parsedUID != "" && typeof parsedUID == "object" )
  {
    for( item in parsedUID )
    {
        if(parsedUID[item])
         $( "#"+item+).collapse('show');
        else
         $( "#"+item+).collapse('hide');
    }
  }
}

$('.expand').click(function() {
    //store the id of the collapsible element
    var uniqueid = {};
    $('.expand').each(function(){
       var getID = $(this).attr('href').replace(/#/g,'');
       uniqueid[getID] = $(this).hasClass('collapsed');
    }); 
    localStorage.setItem('uniqueid', JSON.stringify(uniqueid)); 


});
```

Comment: This won't do it. First it throws a syntax error, and when I fix it, it says "unrecognized expression: "#collapseExample"(…)" (which is the href of the element). Never the less - it doesn't seem to be able to save the item at all. Shouldn't setItem be at the top?

Comment: yes, indeed. I also get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0(…) which is undefined.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me with this. I've been at it for 2 days now. lol

Comment: You are welcome buddy :) Here is the working code https://jsfiddle.net/SPViradiya/nm6tqxsL/

Comment: that is absolutely perfect. You ROCK!

Comment: What if I want to include a toggle rotate of an arrow (and back) in the same script? I'm trying, but all the arrows rotate simultaniously. All the appropriate CSS is there as you can see in the fiddle. What I'm looking for is to toggleCass('rotateOn');

Comment: May be you added in some other fiddle. Its not there in the fiddle you have added. And if it helped you, one up to the comment would be appreciated. :)

Comment: The arrow is the same class as <button class="expand"> so what I need is actually to make the <button class="expand"> to rotate by toggleCass('rotateOn'); - I am upvoting all I can!

Comment: Fantastic. I edited the question with a definite answer. I'm trying to upvote you, but I think my reputation is too low. I'll come back here and upvote once my reputation is built up.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a unique id use Date.now() and append the return value to a given string like:

`var id = "id-" + Date.now(); // id-1477557085096`

The Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: ooo. nice suggestion. Let me try that!

Comment: What's wrong with this?

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.expand').click(function() {
       var uniqueid = "id-" + Date.now(); // id-1477557085096

        localStorage.setItem('uniqueid', JSON.stringify(uniqueid)); $(this).attr('href');

    });


    var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('uniqueid'); 
    if (collapseItem) {
       $(collapseExample).collapse('show')

           $('.expand').click(function() {
       localStorage.removeItem('uniqueid');

  });
    
    }

})